# Replace question mark within a word

Tags: javascript, hl7, mirth

I am getting HL7 messages through with question marks charcters in the middle of words like "can?t and dc?d" and I want to replace them with apostrophe. I was able to replace character (?) at the beginning of the sentence using mystring.replace(/^\?/,"-")
I tried mystring.replace(/['\x3f']/g,"'"); but the problem with this one is it converts all questions marks.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So how do you want them replaced?

Comment: I want to replace them by inserting apostrophe (') instead of question marks. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding problem. Are you sure those are really question marks?

Comment: I received them as question marks, but when I check the source system it shows x92 and x95

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to do this manually to fix the problem.
mystring.replace("?t","'t") and mystring.replace("?d","'d"). This works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You're solving the wrong problem. You probably have a character encoding problem somewhere upstream that is replacing '’' characters with '?'. That means other characters will be incorrectly replaced as well, even if you haven't noticed yet. You should check the upstream systems to make sure they're all properly configured with Unicode, otherwise you're going to have more serious problems.